# Reading in fasta file C++

Tags: c++, file, bioinformatics, fasta

I'm trying to read in a fasta file. I want to remove/ignore the header/info lines that begin with ">" and store the following sequences into sperate strings. Below is the code I have to do that (partially reworked from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/FASTA_format#C++, as what I had originally worked even less). They have a good example of what I want to do.

My problem is given this fasta file:

```
">sequence_1  
MSTAGKVIKCKAAVLWELHKPFTIEDIEVAPPKAHEVRIKMVATGVCRSDDHVVSGTLVTPLPAVLGHE
GAGIVEGVTCVKPGDKVIPLFSPQCGECRICKHPESNFCSRSDLLMPRGTLREGTSRFSCKGKQIHNFI
STSTFSQYTVVDDIAVAKIDGASPLDKVCLIGCGFSTGYGSAVKVAKVTPGSTCAVFGLGGVGLSVIIG
CKAAGAARIIAVDINKDKFAKAKELGATECIYSKPIQEVLQEMTDGGVDFSFEVIGRLDTMTSALLSCH
AACGVSVVVGVPPNAQNLSMNPMLLLLGRTWKGAIFGGFKSKDSVPKLVAKKFPLDPLITHVLPFEKIN
EAFDLLRSGKSIRTVLTF

">sequence_2  
MNQGKVIKCKAAVLWEVKKPFSIEDVEVAPPKAYEVRIKMVAVGICHTDDHVVSGNLVTPLPVILGHEA
AGIVESVGEGVTTVKPGDKVIPLFTCRVCKNPESNYCLKNDLGNPRGTLQDGTRRFTCRGKPIHHFLGT
STFSQYTVVDENAVAKIDAASPLEKVCLIGCGFSTGYGSAVNVAKVTPGSTCAVFGLGGVGLSAVMGCK
AAGAARIIAVDINKDKFAKAKELGATECINPQDYKLPIQEVLKEMTDGSTVIGRLDTMMASLLCCGTSV
IVEDTPASQNLSINPMLLLTGRTWKGAVYGGFKSKEGIPKLVADFMAKKFSLDALITHVLPFEKINEGF
DLLHSGKSIRTVLTF
```

### My output:

```
Sequence 1: MSTAGKVIKCKAAVLWELHKPFTIEDIEVAPPKAHEVRIKMVATGVCRSDDHVVSGTLVTPLPAVLGHEGAGIVEGVTCVKPGDKVIPLFSPQCGECRICKHPESNFCSRSDLLMPRGTLREGTSRFSCKGKQIHNFISTSTFSQYTVVDDIAVAKIDGASPLDKVCLIGCGFSTGYGSAVKVAKVTPGSTCAVFGLGGVGLSVIIGCKAAGAARIIAVDINKDKFAKAKELGATECIYSKPIQEVLQEMTDGGVDFSFEVIGRLDTMTSALLSCHAACGVSVVVGVPPNAQNLSMNPMLLLLGRTWKGAIFGGFKSKDSVPKLVAKKFPLDPLITHVLPFEKINEAFDLLRSGKSIRTVLTF  

Sequence 2: MNQGKVIKCKAAVLWEVKKPFSIEDVEVAPPKAYEVRIKMVAVGICHTDDHVVSGNLVTPLPVILGHEAAGIVESVGEGVTTVKPGDKVIPLFTCRVCKNPESNYCLKNDLGNPRGTLQDGTRRFTCRGKPIHHFLGTSTFSQYTVVDENAVAKIDAASPLEKVCLIGCGFSTGYGSAVNVAKVTPGSTCAVFGLGGVGLSAVMGCKAAGAARIIAVDINKDKFAKAKELGATECINPQDYKLPIQEVLKEMTDGSTVIGRLDTMMASLLCCGTSVIVEDTPASQNLSINPMLLLTGRTWKGAVYGGFKSKEGIPKLVADFMAKKFSLDALITHVLPFEKINEGF
```

The last line or so of Sequence 2 is cut off..... Any help/solutions?

```
void read_in_Protein(string Protein_filename)
{ // read in the sequences
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open(Protein_filename, ios::in);

    if (!myfile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error can not open file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    string Protein_Sequences{};
    string Protein_Seq_names{};

    //        string temp{};

    string Prot_Seq1{};
    string Prot_Seq2{};

    string line{};

    while (getline(myfile, line).good()) {
        //std::cout << "Line input received (" << line.length() << "): " << line << std::endl;
        if (line.empty() || line[0] == '>') { // Identifier marker
            if (!Protein_Seq_names.empty()) { // Print out what we read from the last entry
                //std::cout << "\tReseting to new sequence" << std::endl;
                //                      cout << Protein_Sequences << endl;
                Protein_Seq_names.clear();
                Prot_Seq1 = Protein_Sequences;
            }
            if (!line.empty()) {
                //std::cout << "\tSetting sequence start" << std::endl;
                Protein_Seq_names = line.substr(1);
            }
            //          std::cout << "\tClearing sequences..." << std::endl;
            Protein_Sequences.clear();
        }
        else if (!Protein_Seq_names.empty()) {
            line = line.substr(0, line.length() - 1);
            if (line.find(' ') != string::npos) { // Invalid sequence--no spaces allowed
                //std::cout << "\tSpace found, clearing buffers..." << std::endl;
                Protein_Seq_names.clear();
                Protein_Sequences.clear();
            }
            else {
                //std::cout << "\tAppending line to protein sequence..." << std::endl;
                Protein_Sequences += line;
            }
        }
        //std::cout << "Protein_Sequences: " << Protein_Sequences << std::endl;
    }

    if (!Protein_Seq_names.empty()) { // Print out what we read from the last entry
        //          cout << Protein_Sequences << endl;
        Prot_Seq2 = Protein_Sequences;
    }

    cout << "\nSequence 1: " << Prot_Seq1 << endl;
    cout << Prot_Seq1.length();
    cout << "\nSequence 2: " << Prot_Seq2 << endl;
    cout << Prot_Seq2.length();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see why is the sequence getting cut off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file doesn't end with a new line then the last call to [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will set the `eof` bit to indicate that it reached the end of the file before finding the line ending. As you are checking `.good()` in your while loop the last line will be discarded. You should instead check `!fail()` (or just the boolean value of the stream itself which is [equivalent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to `!fail()`):

```
while (getline(myfile, line))
```

After reading the final line the next iteration of the loop will try to read whilst the stream is in the `eof` state and immediately fail and break out of the loop.